# How to add symbols to assembly after it has been loaded

Tags: c#, symbols, stack-trace

#### Situation:

I am writing C# mod for the game Cities Skylines. when I get exception my stack trace does not include file and line number. this is because the game loads my mod like this:

```cs
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(dllPath));
```

I am aware `Assembly.Load(Byte[], Byte[])` loads the symbols but I cannot change game code.
I do have the pdb files. I just don't know how to load them.

#### Need:

I need the symbols because I'd like my stack trace to have file and line numbers.

#### Question:

Is there any way to add symbols to the assembly after it has been loaded?

Comment: How about load assembly with symbols from assembly without symbols?

Comment: Cool trick but does not work in my case. The game is trying to be clever and searches exported symbols for implementations of several interfaces. If those interfaces do not exist, the game discards the dll.
Also I don't expect people like to use this hack around in every mod they create.